# combine @TestFor and @Integration Annotation grails 3

Tags: grails, annotations, integration-testing, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

I migrate a large Grails 1.3.7 project to 3.1.6.
Tests for Controllers are integration tests. This works fine because the tests inherit from ControllerSpec. Now i´m should be able to do something like this:

```
@Integration
@TestFor(SampleController)
class SampleControllerIntSpec extends Specification {
```

Because the TestFor Annotation allows usage of model/view/.. fields like in Unit tests.

Is there a way to do something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No the `TestFor` annotations are exclusively for unit tests, `Integration` tests are full functional tests in Grails 3 where you should use a client like Geb to send requests to the server and assert responses.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
I know it isn´t possible to do it like this. I have to migrate a lot of tests and i hope there is a workaround to do it like that.
Can you give me a hint?